# Memory leak in SkCanvas::drawText

Tags: c++, skia

I am using Skia for rendering. I am getting memory leak in following code on Mac OS X.
Xcode Instrument shows a memory leak here.

```
//mytext is text in UTF-16 encoding.
//skpaint is a SkPaint *
//canvas is SkCanvas * which is initialized.
canvas->drawText(mytext, mytextlen*sizeof(char16_t), 0, 0, *skpaint);
```

On Windows, it is not showing any memory leak, but on Mac OS X.

I would like to know why is it giving memory leak. Is it something else which is causing this memory leak.

Comment: How do you know it's a leak, and that the line you posted is the offending code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I got this leak while running my application in Instrument.